# Regex: matching XYX where X and Y are any letters

Tags: mysql, node.js, regex

Is there a way to retrieve strings by loosely specified pattern/combination?

**Example**

Data: [AAA, ABA, CAC, CCA, BCB]

Input: XYX

Output: ABA, CAC, BCB

I'm using mySQL regexp function and nodeJS.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Yes there is. Did you try something ?

Comment: You may wish to consider using [LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG](https://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html), which supports the PCRE regex engine (allowing you to use the negative lookahead in `([A-Z])(?!\1)[A-Z]\1`).

Comment: Striped yes, I tried other regexes such as ([A-Z])[A-Z]$.
CarySwoveland thank you, I will get to that, but I am currently trying to make the "\1" part work in mysql, because it doesn't. It is currently matching a string "1" instead of searching for repeats.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: @kosmonaut4333 that version should support the regex in the answer you have.

Comment: @Nick it works. Turns out I needed to use double backslashes. ([A-Z])(?!\\1)[A-Z]\\1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular expression should do the job:

```
/([A-Z])[A-Z]\1/g
```

It will look for an arbitrary capital letter, followed by another letter and a repetition of the first one. The `g` flag  will make it applicable multiple times in a string.

Thanks to Paul for providing the "negative lookahead" fix! To make my answer complete for future readers I incorporate it here into my post:

```
/([A-Z])(?!\1)[A-Z]\1/g
```

Comment: Nice solution and very close. It still matches AAA. But this can be solved using a negative lookahead: `([A-Z])(?!\1)[A-Z]\1` :)

Comment: Thank you very much cars10m and Paul, it works great with JS but it doesn't work with mysql REGEXP function which I'm currently using. Sorry for not specifying, I will edit my question for this matter.

Comment: It finally works, the catch was that I needed to use double backslashes in order to get it to work in mysql. Thank you.

([A-Z])(?!\\1)[A-Z]\\1